# Function definition by variable?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me the advantages of defining an anonymous function and assigning to a variable, contrary to defining by function name.
Ie.

```
var add = function(a, b) { return a+b};
var result = add(1, 2);
```

Contrary to

```
function add(a, b) { return a+b };
var result = add(1, 2);
```

BTW I'm new to javascript but done a lot of C-style coding.

Best regards Ben

Comment: Two styles of writing the same thing...

Comment: Functions are Objects in JavaScript. Yo can do things like var addTwo = add.bind(var a, 2); Further you can assign a Self executing function to a variable so that not all variables are Part of the global scope

Comment: @ChavaG No it is different, if you assign a variable to a function and then you call it before the decleration in Code it is undefined due to hoisting. This behaviour is different from a "normal function"

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann thanks ☺

Comment: thanks for answering even if it's a duplicate ☺ Will look around before asking next time 